# cannot declare pointer to node& in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class node{
public:
    int data;
    vector<node*> children;
};

node* createTree(const vector<int>& nums){
    stack<node*> st;
    node *root = new node(nums[0]);
    st.push(root);
    for(int i=1;i<nums.size();i++){
        if(nums[i]==-1){
            st.pop();
        }else{
            node *n = new node(nums[i]);
            st.top()->children.push_back(n);
            st.push(n);
        }
    }
    return root;
}
void display(node& *root){
    cout << root->data << "->";
    for(node& *child:root->children)
        cout << child->data << " ";
    cout <<"\n";
    for(node& *child:root->children)
        display(child);
}
int main(){
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
        freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
        freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
        freopen("error.txt","w",stderr);
    #endif
    vector<int> nums = {10,20,-1,30,50,-1,60,-1,-1,4,-1,-1};
    node *root = createTree(nums);
    display(root);
    return 0;
}
```

```
<source>:25:20: error: 'root' declared as a pointer to a reference of type 'node &'
void display(node& *root){
                   ^
<source>:27:15: error: 'child' declared as a pointer to a reference of type 'node &'
    for(node& *child:root->children)
              ^
<source>:30:15: error: 'child' declared as a pointer to a reference of type 'node &'
    for(node& *child:root->children)
              ^
```

Here i am trying to implement a generic tree and when i try to compile the program i get an an error message saying that in display function i cannot declare a pointer to `node&`. I know that we cannot create a pointer to a reference since references do not have separate physical address, for example something like `int* &b` would not be permissible but `int& *b` would be permissible.Since here i have used `node& *`, i should not have got any error.Then why the program above is giving error?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I think you're reading your `*` and `&` back-to-front: `int* &b` declares `b` as a reference to a pointer *not* a pointer to a reference.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, but you just have you syntax backwards `node* &`. Declarators are read backwards in C/C++.

Comment: You have started reading `node&* b` from right "b is", and then jump for unknown reason to reading from left, but should continue reading as have stated: "b is", "b is pointer to", "b is pointer to reference to", "b is pointer to reference to node" - obviously is incorrect syntactically declaration.

Comment: @G.M. `int* &b` would definitely not work i am pretty sure of that and `int& *b` would definitely work because the first one is pointer to a reference and the second one is reference to a pointer.

Comment: Again, you got the syntax backwards. The first one is a reference and is valid. The second one is wrong.

Comment: *"`int& *b` would definitely work because the first one is pointer to a reference"* - We're telling you the syntax you're attempting is **wrong**. You can choose to believe us, or your own broken code; but it's not going change the fact that a pointer-to-reference is not a valid type decl; a reference-to-pointer *is*.

Comment: @Abhishekjha Confidence is admirable but, in the face of mounting contrary evidence, at some point it becomes stupidity.

Comment: @john I actually didn't know about this rule, i got to know about this concept via checking it through the compiler and various hit and trials. I apologize for this mistake.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I got the concept. So basically i just did not know this backward rule.

Comment: @Abhishekjha One other point, there no need to use references at all in your for loops, just `for (node* child : root->children)`. The reference is only needed when you are using the loop to modify the values being iterated over. But that's not the case in either of your loops.

Comment: @john I have one more question to ask, is there any convention in c++ that when you use pointer you should attach it with the variable name and when using reference attach it with the name of data type. For example: `int *b` and `int& a`. The reason why this is in my mind is that when when you write `int *a,b,c` then a is pointer variable and b and c are normal integers. However, i am not sure about `int& a,b,c`, would this create three reference variables or one reference variable and two integers

Comment: @Abhishekjha `int& a,b,c` would create one reference variable and two integers.
You can see the [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Pointer_and_Reference_Expressions)

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` - bad idea; not portable (not necessarily even to different versions of the same compiler/standard library). *Never* include that header.

Comment: I don't know if i should ask this question or not, but i have a serious doubt. In my code ;let us say if i write `node n` then this `n` would be created in the stack(i know that stack and heap are not mentioned in the official documentation but still....)?? what does that mean? what i understand from it is that its members would be created in stack ... which means `data` and `children` would be created in stack, But let us say if i write `node *n = new node;` then this would be created in the heap which means that `data` and `children` would be created in the heap?? Am i right...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct about the pointer to a reference vs reference to a pointer but got the syntax wrong.

Pointer to a reference is declared as: `type&* obj`

Reference to a pointer is declared as: `type*& obj`

Thus, the way that you think is "wrong", turns out to be correct:

```
void display(node*& root)
```

Edit: It's easier to imagine this way: `(type*)& obj` vs `(type&)* obj`